# JQuery .animate(); not working with fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've worked with this many times and have had no problem. Animating the height and/or width of a DIV either by `width/height: 'toggle'` or replacing `'toggle'` with specified width/height.

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $('.input-group .Advanced').animate({
       height: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
    });
} , 500);
```

`height: 'toggle'` - [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncs02e47/)
`height: '400px'`  - [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ncyc53g/)

The code snippet works perfectly fine however I need this to be set to a specific height and replacing my `'toggle'` to a fixed height such as `'400px'` does absolutely nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your given height is not working because you have set a `display:none` to your `.Advanced` class. When you use jquery inbuilt `toggle` string it will take care of that and make your hidden element in view.But, when you define your own height you also have to display that element in view otherwise animation will work but not display. You can refer [Jquery animate() reference](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) .It's written there

> Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible as part of the effect. For example, given $( "someElement" ).hide().animate({height: "20px"}, 500), the animation will run, but the element will remain hidden.

You can do this to animate your class

```
setTimeout( function(){
        $('.input-group .Advanced').animate({
           height: '500px',
          opacity:'show'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    } , 500);
```

This will get your hidden element in view.[Demo of your code](http://jsbin.com/nejodiwepo/edit?js,output)

Comment: This doesn't give the slide effect as desired shown when using `width: 'toggle'` however with your answer you provided it gave some much needed insight to modify my `.input-group .Advanced` an initial height of 0

Comment: Yeah, I just focused more on the issue with .animate() and happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.form-control' ).click(function(e) {

    $(this).addClass('InputFreezeFocus');

    $(this).animate({
       width: '400px'
    }, {
        direction: 'left',
        duration: 500,
    });
    setTimeout( function(){
        $('.input-group .Advanced').animate({
           height: '400px',
           opacity: 'toggle'
        }, {
            duration: 500,
        });
    } , 500);
});
```

The `.animate()` method does not make hidden elements visible as part of the effect so you have to toggle the opacity.

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ncyc53g/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your input :)